# Images does not download Properly

Tags: asp.net

I've downlaod the images from particular URL using for loop in case some products having more than 5 images .. when i click the product button some of the images only download not all images..but when i debugg the coressponding code it will download all the images.. how is possible ...

This is My Code

```
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.Count; i++)
            {
                PartNAme = (obj[i].ToString().Split('='))[1];
                _prtnm = PartNAme.ToString().Split(';')[0];


                _final_URI = _URI + _Prod_name + '/' + _prtnm + ".GIF";


                WebClient client = new WebClient();

                string strtempname = DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "").Replace(":", "").Replace(" ", "");

                rnd = new Random(100);

                string _strfile = "PNImage" + strtempname + rnd.Next().ToString() + ".gif";

                string _path = "../Images/PNImage/" + _strfile;

                string _PPath = Server.MapPath(_path);               

                  client.DownloadFile(_final_URI, _PPath); 
}
```

Comment: I am no expert in this, but have you tried using DownloadFileAsync ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the Random variable causes this issue. Try to put 
rnd = new Random(100) out of the loop and see how it works. Usually, the random is the same value if it runs fast.

Comment: tHANKS mR.hOWARD..it will working fine i've to change random number in a seperate function now it will works fine